# KDB+/Q: GRPC implementation?

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, kdb

> gRPC is a modern open source high performance RPC framework that can
> run in any environment. It can efficiently connect services in and
> across data centers with pluggable support for load balancing,
> tracing, health checking and authentication. It is also applicable in
> last mile of distributed computing to connect devices, mobile
> applications and browsers to backend services.

I'm finding GRPC is becoming increasingly more pertinent in backend infrastructure, and would've liked to have it in my favorite language/tsdb kdb+/q.

I was surprised to find that kdb+ does not have a grpc implementation. Obviously, the (https://code.kx.com/q/interfaces/protobuf/)
package doesn't support the parsing of rpc's, is there anything quantitatively preventing there being a KDB+ implementation of the rpc requests/services etc. found in grpc?

Why would one not want to implement rpc's (grpc) in kdb+ and would it be a good idea to wrap a c++/c implemetation therin inorder to achieve this functionality.

Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting post:
https://zimarev.com/blog/event-sourcing/myth-busting/2020-07-09-overselling-event-sourcing/

outlines event sourcing, which I think might be a better fit for kdb?

What is the main issue with services using RPC calls to exchange information? Well, it’s the high degree of coupling introduced by RPC by its nature. The whole group of services or even the whole system can go down if only one of the services stops working. This approach diminishes the whole idea of independent components.

In my practice I hardly encounter any need to use RPC for inter-service communication. Partially because I often use Event Sourcing, more about it later. But we always use asynchronous communication and exchange information between services using events, even without Event Sourcing.

For example, an order microservice in an e-commerce system needs customer data from the customer microservice. These dependencies between microservices are not ideal. Other microservices can go down and synchronous RESTful requests over https do not scale well due to their blocking nature. If there was a way to completely eliminate dependencies between microservices completely the result would be a more robust architecture with less bottlenecks.

You don’t need Event Sourcing to fix this issue. Event-driven systems are perfectly capable of doing that. Event Sourcing can eliminate some of the associated issues like two-phase commits, but again, not a requirement to remove the temporal coupling from your system.